# Class 'Anhskohbo\NoCaptcha\NoCaptchaServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, error-handling, recaptcha

I tried adding Recaptcha through the Anhskohbo package but there is the error of no class found.

Answer (score 0):

This package comes with laravel framework in my case I was upgrading the framework so I replaced  the file app/config.php to new version
and it work
It tells you that it does not exist because it does not really exist. I think that if you download it, it will't work. You may have to take the full version of laravel framework as it is
or create new project for same version and tack app/config.php to your project
or reinstall by  after delete vendor

> composer install